# Android nullpointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

To be short...I have a widget, you can see the important part below

```
public class ExampleWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
private PhoneStateListener listener;
private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state) {
            // removed the code
        }

    };

    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(listener,
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE);

}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    super.onDisabled(context);
}
}
```

and I am receiving nullpointer exception at `telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);` when I am removing the widget from the main screen.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where does the NPE happen exactly? Right within the line you stated or inside .listen()? Do you have a config-activity for your widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`context.getSystemService()` may return `null` and you do not prove `telephonyManager` if it is `null`. If the name identified by `Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE` does not exist in the system the `telephonyManager` will be `null`.

In addition to your comment:

```
@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    if (telephonyManager!=null){
        telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }
    super.onDisabled(context);
}
```

If you need to run this code in the `onDisabled` Method you should initialize the telephonyManager. It smells like the `onDisabled` method is called somehow before `onUpdate` or if you have two different instances.

Comment: It's not null, because I am using it, and it works, I just removed the code where I am using it. Just in onDisabled() it says it's null.

Comment: The method isn't called before onUpdate(). I tracked with Log.

Comment: Did you also track if it is the same instance of this AppWidgetProvider ?

Comment: No, i didn't. How do I do that?

Comment: The one in onCreate() is 1156858336, the one in onDisabled() is 0.

Comment: @AlexAdy let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2266/discussion-between-fyr-and-alex-ady)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ExampleWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
private PhoneStateListener listener;
private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {


    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(listener,
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE);

}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    super.onDisabled(context);
}
listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state) {
            // removed the code
        }

    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check `telephonyManager` to see if it is null.

```
if(telephonyManager==null){
    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
}
telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
```

Comment: If I make it like that it doesn't remove the listener. I am trying to figure out why is telephonyManager null.

Answer (score 0):

I got same probem.
Actually problem disapeared after I made all null fields static.
Looks like it;s really another instance of provider who gets onDisabled.