# How to destroy object of PhoneStateListener class?

Tags: android, listener, state, destroy

In some cases I don't want listen to state of my phone.
How to destroy object of PhoneStateListener class?

I create object this way

```
 try {
     phoneCallListener = new WnetPlayerPhoneCallListener();
     TelephonyManager mTM = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     mTM.listen(phoneCallListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
 } catch(Exception e) {
     Log.e("PhoneCallListener", "Exception: "+e.toString()); 
 }
```

Answer (score 17):

In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen%28android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int%29) it states to pass the listener object and flag [LISTEN_NONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#LISTEN_NONE) to unregister a listener.

Answer (score 10):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6995651/321697), you should keep a reference to `TelephonyManager` and `WnetPlayerPhoneCallListener`, and set it to disabled, like so:

```
mTm.listen(phoneCallListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
```

Why they don't just have standard `addListener()` and `removeListener()` methods, I don't know, but this seems to be the accepted method for solving your problem.